# Chart.Js- y-axis line is misplaced on line chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart with bars and lines. Line datas are correct but it seems to aggregate line values ​​in the same category when placing line charts. I thought it was because the y-axis is stacked=true, but I can't set this property to false. Because of bar charts, y-axis has to be stacked=true. How can I fix this problem?

```
const barData = {

                labels: lblList,
                datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'GP Hedef',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(12,0,0)',
                    type: 'line',
                    borderDash: [10],
                    data: mList,
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: 'rgb(12,0,0)',
                    spanGaps: true,
                    fullWidth: false
                },

                {
                    label: 'MOM Hedef',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(122, 17, 17, 1)',
                    type: 'line',
                    borderDash: [10],
                    data: hList,
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(122, 17, 17, 1)',
                    spanGaps: true,
                    fullWidth: false

                },

                {
                    categoryPercentage:0.2, 
                    data: gList,
                    backgroundColor: cGList,
                    maxBarThickness: 12,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    label: 'GP',
                    stack: 1
                },

                {
                    label: 'Process',
                    data: pList,
                    backgroundColor: cPList,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    maxBarThickness: 25,
                    stack:2
                },

                {

                    label: 'Waiting',
                    data: wList,
                    backgroundColor: cWList,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    maxBarThickness: 25,
                    stack:2

                },

                {
                    data: tList 
                }
 
                ]
            }

            new Chart(ctx0, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barData,
                options: {

                    tooltips: {
                        displayColors: false,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(150, 50, 0)',
                        titleFontColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                        bodyFontColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                        callbacks: {
                            title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                return;
                            },
                            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                const label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                                const cycle = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                                return label + ': ' + cycle + ' sn';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'İstasyon Çevrim Süreleri',
                        fontSize: 20
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }]
                    }

                }
            });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obchy.png)

In this case, black line correctly placed in y-axis, but the other one must be placed 23 in y-axis. It seems like brown line placed in 41 in y-axis which is 23+18.

I need to place the brown line in 23(in this case of course, the location will change according to the content of the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by giving stack IDs to my bars which I want them to get stacked in y-axis(don't give IDs to line charts which I don't want them to get stacked) and removing " yAxes: [{ stacked: true }] " from my options. Here is the codes:

```js
    const barData = {
                labels: lblList,
                datasets: [

                {
                    label: '',
                    backgroundColor: color,
                    type: 'line',
                    borderDash: [10],
                    data: lList,
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: color,
                    spanGaps: true,
                    fullWidth: false
                },
                {
                    label: 'GP Hedef',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(12,0,0)',
                    type: 'line',
                    borderDash: [10],
                    data: mList,
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: 'rgb(12,0,0)',
                    spanGaps: true,
                    fullWidth: false
                },

                {
                    label: 'MOM Hedef',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(122, 17, 17, 1)',
                    type: 'line',
                    borderDash: [10],
                    data: hList,
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(122, 17, 17, 1)',
                    spanGaps: true,
                    fullWidth: false
                },

                {
                    categoryPercentage:0.2, 
                    data: gList,
                    backgroundColor: cGList,
                    maxBarThickness: 12,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    label: 'GP',
                    stack: 'stack 1'
                },

                {
                    label: 'Process',
                    data: pList,
                    backgroundColor: cPList,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    maxBarThickness: 25,
                    stack:'stack 2'
                },

                {

                    label: 'Waiting',
                    data: wList,
                    backgroundColor: cWList,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    maxBarThickness: 25,
                    stack:'stack 2'

                },

                {
                    data: tList 
                }
                ]}

            new Chart(ctx0, {

                type: 'bar',
                data: barData,
                options: {

                    tooltips: {
                        displayColors: false,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(150, 50, 0)',
                        titleFontColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                        bodyFontColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                        callbacks: {
                            title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                return;
                            },
                            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                const label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                                const cycle = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                                return label + ': ' + cycle + ' sn';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'İstasyon Çevrim Süreleri',
                        fontSize: 20
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }]
                        //yAxes: [{
                        //    stacked: true
                        //}]
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you stack your Y axes, so the data is stacked on top of the other data and thus gets added as you noted. To get the behaviour you want you need to remove this part of your config:

```js
yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
```

Comment: Yes, i got it. But, bars need to appear on top of each other. When I set stacked=false, the linecharts are placed properly, but this time bars don't look like they should.